# Nested Attributes Error: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

My Item model belongs to my Order model, and my Order model has many Items. When I attempt to pass in the following params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mPKksp+W5lZc7+lrc90trtCzX+UtPj4PI8boNf7vb+nneMF/J5SSBz8Nmh+CQ//DkmuVP2MJf7gS3oLqpZcM2Q==", "order"=>{"special_instructions"=>"", "item_attributes"=>{"topping_ids"=>["1", "2", "5"]}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

I receive the following error:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

The error occurs in my create action in my Orders controller:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
```

This is what my params method looks like:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:completed, :special_instructions, items_attributes: [ :size, topping_ids: [] ])
end
```

Here is my Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

Here is my Item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :sizes
  has_many :item_toppings
  has_many :toppings, through: :item_toppings
  has_many :inverse_item_toppings, class_name: 'ItemTopping', foreign_key: 'item_id'
  has_many :inverse_toppings, through: :inverse_item_toppings, source: :item
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sizes, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And here are the relevant parts of my schema

```
create_table "item_toppings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "item_id"
  t.integer  "topping_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  t.string   "description"
  t.boolean  "seasonal",    default: false
  t.boolean  "active",      default: false
  t.string   "kind"
  t.integer  "toppings_id"
  t.string   "qualifier"
  t.integer  "order_id"
end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
  t.boolean  "completed",            default: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "special_instructions"
end
```

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with some part of my params needing to be an array instead of a hash, but I can't figure out my specific problem based off of similar posts I've worked through.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I can tell, because I have a has_many relationship, my items_attributes value needed to be an array of hashes:

```
{"items_attributes"=>[{"topping_ids"=>['1', '2', '5', '30']}]}
```

Instead of

```
{"items_attributes"=>{"topping_ids"=>['1', '2', '5', '30']}}
```

I believe the message error is related to Ruby expecting an array index – not a hash key.

Comment: How did you change it to be an array of hashes?

Comment: In my HTML I added square brackets to the name of the relevant HTML element, like so: name: items_attributes[][topping_ids]

Comment: Can you explain what the empty array is doing before [topping_ids]?

Comment: The empty array makes it so the items_attributes value is an array, so items_attributes[] will make the params "item_attributes"=>[{}] whereas without the array it will just be "item_attributes"=>{}

Comment: oh my god thanks for this answer, saved my day

Answer (score 0):

guessing:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
```

to:

```
order_params_hash = order_params 

order_params_hash[:order][:item_attributes][:topping_ids].map! do |topping_id| 
  topping_id.to_i 
end

@order = Order.new(order_params_hash)
```

Comment: Thanks for writing up this nice piece of code! From what I can tell, AR is not that picky about type. It turns out I needed to pass an array of hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're passing an array of strings to `topping_ids` and the corresponding database column is set to store integers.

You could call `to_i` to explicitly convert the array of strings into integers, or pass an array of integers instead.

Comment: Passing in strings appears to work fine. I think ActiveRecord isn't that picky about type.